# Can java.io.serializable be preventing garbage collection?

Tags: android

I have a network application that receives various DTO objects from a server. These DTO's contain other DTO'. In order to be able to pass them between Activities in the bundle, I've had them, and their nested DTO's implement the java.io.Serializable interface.

Taking stack dumps of my application and inspecting them in the Eclipse Memory Analyzer I'm seeing that there are hundreds of these DTO's that aren't being garbage collected. So it's obvious I'm doing something wrong.

My question is, as the title suggests. Is this a result of the serializable interface, and if so what do  other programmers usually do to ensure said objects are picked up by the gc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherently troublesome about Serializable objects and garbage collection that I can think of.

However, it is very possible and relatively easy to leak an Activity (which in turn will leak whatever bundles and serialized objects are in the bundles associated with the Activity.)

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html

The golden rule for making your objects eligible for garbage collection is to ensure that none of your other live objects holds a reference to them.

I would start by using Eclipse MAT to see if your Activity is not getting garbage collected and start there.

Comment: Your right. The issue had everything to do with the Adapters not releasing the Lists of objects passed into them. Problem solved.